# Send email with subject and body Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using the following code in my Xamarin.Forms project to open the native email client on the device with some information prepopulated in the body, but the email client on Android opens without a set body and subject; it only has the `mailto` property.

The following code works for iOS, but on Android, it opens the email clientand only displays `mailto`.

```cs
string body = "Name : "+"\r\n" +NameLabel.Text +"Phone : "+Phonelabel.Text +"\r\n"+ "Email : "+ EmailLabel.Text ;

string strMailTo = @"mailto:test@gmail.com?Subject="profile"&Body="+body;

Device.OpenUri(new Uri(strMailTo));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used in Xamarin.Forms DependencyService and this code:

```cs
var email = new Intent (Android.Content.Intent.ActionSend);
email.PutExtra (Android.Content.Intent.ExtraEmail,
new string[]{"person1@xamarin.com", "person2@xamrin.com"} );
email.PutExtra (Android.Content.Intent.ExtraCc,
new string[]{"person3@xamarin.com"} );
email.PutExtra (Android.Content.Intent.ExtraSubject, "Hello Email");
email.PutExtra (Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText,
"Hello from Xamarin.Android");
```

[it full example](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/networking/email/send_an_email/)

Answer (score 5):

I think you can try this plugin. I have used for some apps and works fine. It's PCL.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugins.Messaging/

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. I add plugin from nugget. But I have exception (Java.lang.InvocationTargetException)when code execute . I add pluggin and inside .droid and .ios projects in xamarin form app ?

Comment: SMS and phone call it is fine but email task doesn't run ... (tested with android device).

Comment: Also with github example? Strange. Have you fill all fields? Title, body... Try to contact the author if you have problems again.

Comment: Yes I try and github example but nothing happened.thanks for your time .

Comment: I use Dependency Servises and now play very well !!

Answer (score 3):

I have code that uses `Device.OpenUri` from Xamarin Forms. I think perhaps your quotes are confusing it:

```
Device.OpenUri(new Uri("mailto:email@test.com?subject=MobileTing&body=A message for you consideration."));
```